# How to access a remote site using the command line (with drush)?

Tags: shell, command-line, drush

I don´t know how to use drush nor the command line, so I´ve started to read some tutorials, and watch some videos. I´ve installed the drush windows installer, because I have windows.

The thing is that all examples I´ve read so far, start with localhost. What if I have my devel installation in a shared hosting or a VPS, in the cloud? How to access that?

Using my ftp program, I access it using hostname ftp.mysite.com the username and the password to that account. How may I do that with the command line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an excellent video for setting up drush to manage drupal (including remote access) in this link. http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/PHP-at-Scale-on-the-Microsoft-Platform/10-Managing-Drupal-on-Windows-with-Drush

Your answer will come at 27 minutes into the video.

Even i started using Drush lately and this video was very helpful. Encourage you to go through it.